# Can't write this method?

Tags: java, methods, properties

I need to create a pizza ordering system. I have created a array list of pizza toppings and each pizza topping must have a cost property associated with it, then the user can pick the toppings they want and the cost of each topping will be added up and the total cost of the whole pizza will be displayed. But I don't know how to associate a cost with each topping. I have been told that I can access the cost through a get/set method and store it in a private member variable. But I don't know how to do this?

I've also been told that the Pizza class should have a special method to add toppings. After a Pizza object is created, that method would be called repeatedly to add whatever toppings are to be added to the pizza. The Topping class could have the name and cost for the topping.

But  I don't know how I would write this method... My arrayList is as follows:

```
private List<String> Toppings = new ArrayList<String>();

public void arrayList(){

        Toppings.add("Pepperoni"); 
        Toppings.add("Chicken");
        Toppings.add("Ham");
        Toppings.add("Onion");
    }
```

Can anyone help as this is a major stumbling block that I can't overcome?

Comment: map: "Pepperoni -> $0.75", "Chicken -> $0.80", "Caviar -> $50.00"

Comment: Try creating a Topping Class that has a type (such as "Onion") and a cost, such as 0.99. Your Pizza class should have a Collection for storing toppings.

Comment: Change the question title maybe? So it's useful for future readers with the same problem?

Comment: So if I used a map, would that then allow the user to input which topping(s) they wanted on the pizza, print the cost for each topping, and then allow me to add up all the costs at the end and print one whole cost?

Comment: Also what would you suggest I change the title to?

Answer (score 0):

1) Define the map with all toppings:

```
private Map<String, Double> toppingsMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

2) Fill the pizza with some toppings as in your example

3) Get the pizza toppings description and use it to get total prize of added toppings:

```
for (String topping : toppingsInPizza) {
     total += (Double) toppingsMap.get(topping);
}
```

*It is **highly** discouraged to start `variable` names with uppercase in `Java`.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the cost must be accessible through a get/set method, could I still do this with a map?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question...In my example you get prize with a `get`, `Map` have already `Map::put` `Map::get` methods... If you want to define your own ones put the `Map` in an external class and define the getters and setters you need

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider redesigning this code and use the Decorator pattern. You will gain extensibility by being able to add ingredients without modifying existing code. Here is a great link that shows how it is done with via a coffee making scenario.  [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) Plus this is a desired approach for this problem.